# g++ -fsyntax-only unit test

Tags: g++

I'm trying to figure out if

```
g++ -fsyntax-only
```

does only syntax checking or if it expands templates too.

Thus, I ask stack overflow for help:

Is there a way to write a program so that syntactically it's valid, but when template expansion is done, an error occurs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way to write a program so that syntactically it's valid, but when template expansion is done, an error occurs?

Depends on whether your definition of *syntactically valid* is `g++`'s `-fsyntax-only` or not.

The following simple test program illustrates this and, I believe, answers your question:

```
// test.cpp
template< bool > struct test;
template< > struct test< true > { };

int main(void) {
  test< false > t;
  return 0;
}
```

Attempting to build:

```
$ g++ /tmp/sa.cpp
test.cpp: In function `int main()':
test.cpp:6: error: aggregate `test< false> t' has incomplete type and
  cannot be defined

$ g++ -fsyntax-only /tmp/sa.cpp
test.cpp: In function `int main()':
test.cpp:6: error: aggregate `test< false> t' has incomplete type and
  cannot be defined
```

So yes, **`-fsyntax-only` *does* perform template expansion**.

Comment: The English language fails to contain words to describe how awesome/amazing you are. (I've been trying to figure out why compile times are so long; and apparently it's not template expansion.)

Comment: @anon: what takes the most time during compilation is optimization